# Why can't I restart my react-native application?

Tags: react-native

I'm new at react-native.

I reached to start my application but when I want to restart it I got this :

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/tree-kill/index.js:83
    ps.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at buildProcessTree (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/tree-kill/index.js:83:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/tree-kill/index.js:104:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ChildProcess.onClose (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/tree-kill/index.js:99:31)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:395:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:610:12)
```

Why do I get this ?
I start my react-native app with npm start !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I had to remove the file .expo in my folder.